# How to position a Weapons model in a first person shooter with XNA

Tags: xna, matrix, models, projection-matrix

I am building a first person shooter and positioning the weapons is hard. I am trying to get the bat to look like you are holding it but I keep trying things and they don't appear in the positions I want them to be in. Here is what I did with one version of the function.

```
void DrawModelModel(Model model, Matrix world)
    {
        Vector3 modelPosition = Vector3.Zero;
        float modelRotation = 0.0f;
        Viewport viewport = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
        float aspectRatio = (float)viewport.Width / (float)viewport.Height;
        // Set the position of the camera in world space, for our view matrix.
        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);
        // Copy any parent transforms.
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
            // as our camera and projection.
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                effect.View =  Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                    Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(35.0f), aspectRatio,
                    1.0f, 10000.0f) ;
            }
            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

[image: Createperspectiveview]

Here is what I did with a different version of the function.

```
void DrawModelModel(Model model, Matrix world)
    {
        Vector3 modelPosition = Vector3.Zero;
        float modelRotation = 0.0f;
        Viewport viewport = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
        float aspectRatio = (float)viewport.Width / (float)viewport.Height;
        // Set the position of the camera in world space, for our view matrix.
        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);
        // Copy any parent transforms.
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
            // as our camera and projection.
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                effect.View =  Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                    Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter(-2.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 10000.0f) ;
            }
            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

[image: Using Off Center]

What matrix can I use to get the bat model to appear realistically as if you are really holding it in a first person view. I am new to matrices so my knowledge of them is basic. What matrix should I use or what parameters with my current matrix should I be editing? I am thinking the projection matrix is what I need to be editing, but I am very confused at this point. Any help would be great.

Comment: Remember, your title isn't a Google search. It's a sentence describing your problem. Unless a "Shooter XNA" is a thing, ditch the tag at the end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using bone transforms. I suggest you read up on bone animation in blender. You can create a chain of bones that represent arms, holding the bat, and animating that in blender. Then just export the model, including the animations, and you can use the bone animation you made yourself.

Download blender and follow this tutorial: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Your_First_Animation/2.Animation

Comment: That's a great idea and I am going to look into that, but how would I position the model to be on the lower left or right side?

Comment: If you make a skeleton, or "armature" as blender calls it, you will have an array of bone transforms. These bone transforms are simply matrices. If you want to put the bat in the hand of the skeleton, and the hand is - for example - at index 4 in the array, you would do something like this: `effect.world = transforms[4] * matrix.createrotationY(PlayerRotation) * matrix.createtranslation(PlayerPosition)` with "PlayerPosition" obviously being the current position of the player in the game world, and "PlayerRotation" being his rotation in radians.